# input vs variable comparison isn't working?

Tags: bash

Here is a random number generator followed by a line clear timer and you are then to try and input the number that you saw. I cant seem to set up the comparison between the randNum variable and the input. I tried setting a defined value for the input as well and still receive an error "command not found" when checking input vs randNum variable

```
n=$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM; let "n %= 10000000000";
echo $n

for i in {5..1}; do echo $i; sleep 1; tput cuu1; tput el; done
tput cuu1; tput el

echo "what was that number?"
#read input
input=999999999
if [$input == $n]
then
echo "you are correct"
else
echo "you are incorrect"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shells need spaces around brackets `[` and `]` when used for this purpose (replacement syntax for the `test` command), and you should better use `-eq` instead of `==` for numeric comparison:

```
if [ $input -eq $n ]
```

Comment: wow, I literally ran -eq for 20 mins trying things to realize i didn't have spaces around my brackets.... Thank you

Comment: I would add that if "input" is read from stdin or somewhere else it should be enclosed in double quotes just to avoid run time errors. Like this: 
if [ "$input" -eq $n ]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the arithmetic comparison, rather than the old `test`command (a.k.a. `[`) then you can avoid these issues.  Spaces here are less important inside the brackets:

```
if (( input == n ))
```

Note that the leading `$` is not required (and using it can cause issues)